# Is It possible to get the details of windows operating system last backup details in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-10, desktop

I am trying to create a WPF application which shows Windows OS Last backup time and date.I tried with `EventLogger` but I couldn't find the details. Is there any way to get windows Last backup time and date?

Comment: Did you check the registry keys if there's a restore date?

Comment: @Gnqz No I tried but there is no registry keys.

Comment: Are you sure that there is information about the date of the last backup at all. The last thing I can think of is checking the date of creation of the System file with the restoring point.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Environment Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)

> Provides information about, and means to manipulate, the current
>   environment and platform. This class cannot be inherited.

**EDIT:**

You can also check this: [Creating System Restore Points using PInvoke](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38205/Creating-System-Restore-Points-using-PInvoke)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct RestorePointInfo
{
    public int dwEventType;     // The type of event
    public int dwRestorePtType;     // The type of restore point
    public Int64 llSequenceNumber;  // The sequence number of the restore point
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MaxDescW + 1)] 
    public string szDescription;    // The description to be displayed so 
                //the user can easily identify a restore point
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any information about backups there...

Comment: There is no information about backup there